# SQLite onUpgrade with 4 database versions

Tags: android, sqlite

How is the proper way to execute an SQLiteOpenHelper's onUpgrade method, when we have 4 database versions and we have added a new field to the user table in each version?

Variant A: // No "break" after each case, does it keep running for case 2 and 3?

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
    switch (version_old) {
    case 1:
        database.execSQL(addPostcodeFieldToUserTable);
    case 2:
        database.execSQL(addGenderFieldToUserTable);
    case 3:
        database.execSQL(addEmailSubscriptionFieldToUserTable);
        break;
    }
}
```

Variant B:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
    switch (version_old) {
    case 1:
        database.execSQL(addPostcodeFieldToUserTable);
        break;
    case 2:
        database.execSQL(addPostcodeFieldToUserTable);
        database.execSQL(addGenderFieldToUserTable);
        break;
    case 3:
        database.execSQL(addPostcodeFieldToUserTable);
        database.execSQL(addGenderFieldToUserTable);
        database.execSQL(addEmailSubscriptionFieldToUserTable);
        break;
    }
```

But what do we do in the case when a user had version 1 of the DB, then missed version 2 and upgraded the app with version 3?

Variant 3:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
    if(version_old==1 && current_version==2) {
        database.execSQL(addPostcodeFieldToUserTable);

    } else if(version_old==2 && current_version==3) {
        database.execSQL(addGenderFieldToUserTable);

    } else if(version_old==3 && current_version==4) {
        database.execSQL(addEmailSubscriptionFieldToUserTable);

    } else if(version_old==1 && current_version==3) {
        database.execSQL(addPostcodeFieldToUserTable);
        database.execSQL(addGenderFieldToUserTable);

    } else if(version_old==1 && current_version==4) {
        database.execSQL(addPostcodeFieldToUserTable);
        database.execSQL(addGenderFieldToUserTable);
        database.execSQL(addEmailSubscriptionFieldToUserTable);

    } else if(version_old==2 && current_version==4) {
        database.execSQL(addGenderFieldToUserTable);
        database.execSQL(addEmailSubscriptionFieldToUserTable);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say **B**: if `a user had version 1 of the DB, then missed version 2 and upgraded the app with version 3`, then s/he'll get **all** the upgrades anyway. Even the unnecessary previous ones (which, I hope, are **managed to gracefully fail** if the table/s are already in the db).

Comment: What If I had been using version A of the onUpgrade method for 3 versions now, will it break something for existing users when they download the newest versions of the app where I use variant B?

Comment: Also can you elaborate on the "managed to gracefully fail" thing

Comment: By "managed to gracefully fail" I mean that each method which adds a table  (i.e.: `addPostcodeFieldToUserTable()`) has to check if the table exist before trying to create it (or simply use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`). So, an existing table won't be overwritten. And no error will be generated.

Comment: the addPostcodeFieldToUserTable is an "ALTER TABLE " method, forgot to mention that

Comment: So, check if a column exists in the table before trying to execute the ALTER statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No "break" after each case, does it keep running for case 2 and 3?

Yes. A common practice is to add a comment like

```
// fallthrough
```

to indicate the missing `break` is intentional.

> But what do we do in the case when a user had version 1 of the DB, then missed version 2 and upgraded the app with version 3?

`onUprade()` would be called with `oldVersion` 1 and `newVersion` 3. The code should update the database to version 3 of your schema.

Which variant to use depends on which is the most comfortable for you to maintain. I'd personally go with something like variant A since it has the least code.

Comment: This is a relief because I had been using variant A for the first three versions :)

Answer (score 3):

What you could also do is make the onUpgrade a recursive call,

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
switch (version_old) {
case 1:
    database.execSQL(addPostcodeFieldToUserTable);
    onUpgrade(database,version_old++,current_version);
    break;
case 2:
    database.execSQL(addPostcodeFieldToUserTable);
    database.execSQL(addGenderFieldToUserTable);
    onUpgrade(database,version_old++,current_version)
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

u get the idea, so it will upgrade to the latest version and quit calling itself.

Comment: The "must do" is quite strongly said. There's no must.

Comment: Yes, this could work, and it comes to personal preference what approach to take.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `switch` without `break`s is counterintuitive.

A common pattern is to use a series of `if`s instead:

```
if (version_old < 2) {
    database.execSQL(addPostcodeFieldToUserTable);
}
if (version_old < 3) {
    database.execSQL(addGenderFieldToUserTable);
}
if (version_old < 4) {
    database.execSQL(addEmailSubscriptionFieldToUserTable);
}
```